CANoe Physical to functional requests
I need to control CANoe with Python using win32com and change Physical Requests to Functional Group Request. This can also be seen in Diagnostics/ISO TP Configuration under CAN Networks under Diagnostic Description Configuration.
Does anyone have an idea how this could be accomplished?
I couldn't find a suitable solution for it.

To my knowledge, there is currently no way to change the mode of a diagnostic description nor to add it with a different mode than PNR via COM

There is an option in the Diagnostics/ISO TP Configuration window to switch between functional and physical.

